# What prevents the diffusion of proton gradient in Gram (+) bacteria

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, metabolism

The proton gradient in bacteria is important to power FTPase and flagella. How do Gram (+) bacteria maintain a proton gradient without a periplasm (Gram (-)) or intermembrane space (mitochondria). Why don't the protons diffuse away from the Gram (+) bacteria when they are exported?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on what we do here. Please note the page on [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). Ideally your question should demonstrate an attempt to find the answer yourself, and, no - "I google searched and didn't find anything" isn't an attempt. The answers to this should be easily found in your microbiology textbook!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Gram + bacteria use a proton gradient for F-type ATPase?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16258/how-do-gram-bacteria-use-a-proton-gradient-for-f-type-atpase)